# Dragging a div to resize an image.

Tags: jquery, drag

I tried to setup a div so that when dragged, my image's width grows and shrinks the same distance.  However, if I move my div 1px, my image's width changes more than 1px.

Any suggestion?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ghm4N/1/

```
function drag(el){
        var dragging = dragging || false, x, handle_left, handle;
        el.onmousedown = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            dragging = true;
            handle = $(e.target);

            x = e.clientX;
            handle_left = handle.position().left;

            window.onmousemove = function(e){
                if(dragging == true){
                    var distance_w = e.clientX - x;

                    handle.css('left', (handle_left + distance_w)+'px');

                    $('.normal').css('width', $('.normal').width() + distance_w);
                    console.log(distance_w);
                    console.log($('.normal').width()+distance_w);
                    return false;
                }
            };
            window.onmouseup = function(e){
                dragging && (dragging = false);
            };
        };
    };

    var el = $('.btn');
    for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
        drag(el[i]);
    };
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">     
    <div class="wp_normal">
        <div class="normal">
            <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/284263a747fda7627c76920071ef580d/tumblr_mf8mf2FzZm1qm9rypo1_1280.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wp_normal{
    position: absolute; z-index: 1;
    left: 0;    top: 0;
}
.normal{
    position: relative;
    width:500px;    height: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.normal img{
    position:absolute;
    width: 1024px;  height: 280px;
}
.btn{
    position: absolute; z-index: 3;
    width: 100px;   height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghm4N/2/)**</kbd>

You were missing lot of things in your MATH

- detect the mouse position INSIDE the clicked *handle* element
- get the *handle* width / 2
- dynamically get the DIV to manipulate
- Get the current DIV width (might change over time manipulating your elements)
- Code validation!
- Still you'll have to add in your math the offset().left one day the images will not be at '0'-left
- and spot what I forgot to mention

```
$(function(){


        function drag(el){

            var mDown = false,
                x, // mouse X
                handle_left,
                handle,
                handle_width2, /* missing this */
                clickedAt,     /* and this */
                $normal,       /* and this! */
                normal_width;  /* and this! */


            el.onmousedown = function( e ) {

                e.preventDefault();
                mDown = true;
                x = e.clientX;
                handle = $(e.target);
                handle_width2 = handle.width()/2;
                $normal = handle.prev('div').find('.normal'); /* you were missing this */
                normal_width = $normal.width(); /* and this */
                handle_left = handle.position().left;
                clickedAt = x-handle_left; /* gives the mouse position inside "handle" */
                /* you'll have to add to this math the .normal offset().left */

                window.onmousemove = function( e ) {

                    if(mDown){   
                        x = e.clientX;
                        handle.css({left: x-clickedAt });
                        $normal.css({ width : handle.position().left + handle_width2  });
                        return false;
                    }

                };
                el.onmouseup = function(e){
                    mDown = false;
                };
            };
        }


        var el = $('.btn');
        for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
            drag(el[i]);
        }

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ghm4N/4/ I tried to limit drag the handle can't over the space, did I miss something? thanks..

Comment: Will be great if it work for Y and X drag with the resizing div at the bottom right. http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/c4wYE/

Answer (score 1):

Bad math.  With every step you adjusted the width of normal *and* applied delta X.  You needed use the base width just like you used the handle_left.  Also don't forget `var` for variable declaration -- they'll be part of the global scope if you don't and that'll get you later.

```
el.onmousedown = function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var dragging = true,
        handle = $(e.target),
        x = e.clientX,
        handle_left = handle.position().left,
        normalWidth = $('.normal').width();  // base width

    window.onmousemove = function(e){
        if(dragging == true){
            var distance_w = e.clientX - x;
            handle.css('left', (handle_left + distance_w)+'px');
            // reused width at start and applied delta
            $('.normal').css('width', normalWidth + distance_w);
            // ... rest of code
```